# CSS selector based on table border value

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I want to access a `table` in a page through a CSS selector.

The structure of the table is as follow:

```
<table border="1" width="560" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
     <td height="28" colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFF...>
 </tr>
</table>
```

basically I need a jquery or css selector in one line to access the `table` with `border=1`

there is no class or id associated with the `table` and parent child mapping for nth access also not possible

basically a selector for `table` where `table border=1` (`border = 1` is not inside `style=""` ), it is just HTML markup

```
<table border=1"> ....</table>
```

Comment: Is this you want `table[border=1]`?

Comment: As an aside it's worth pointing out that using inline attributes for presentation, such as `width`, `cellspacing` and `bgcolor`, is deprecated, and should really be moved to the stylesheet, to use CSS.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

> **[attr=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px
}
table[border="1"] {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Note:** I would advise however to not use the `border` HTML tag, since it is deprecated. To  style the `table` with a `border` you can use the property `border` in CSS.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
table[border="1"]{
  background: red;
}
```

And if you only want to check if there is a border attribute:

```
table[border]{
  background: blue;
}
```

You can find more info about this here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors